# Is the projection from the fiber product flat?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I heard this, but can't figure out a reason:
Let $X,Y$ be $S$-schemes. Is the projection map $X\times Y \rightarrow Y$ flat? I want to pull back a flat coherent sheaf from $Y$, and want it to stay flat over $Y$.

Comment: I guess you consider the fiber product. It is flat, if $X$ is flat over $S$.

Comment: @Sasha Yes, fiber product as in the title. This seems to make sense. In my case, actually $X=\mathbb{P}(V)$ for some vector bundle $V$ on $S$. If I am not mistaken this is flat over $S$.

Comment: Indeed, $X$ is flat over $S$, and $X \times_S Y \cong \mathbb{P}_Y(f^*V)$, where $f$ is the morphism $Y \to S$.